# Can haproxy perform both tcp and http check at the same time on a service?

Tags: haproxy

When I run haproxy with both TCP and HTTP health check on two backends it sends `503 Service Unavailable` error and does not identify any of the backend server although they are up. Both the health checks work individually but when they both are setup together it sends error. Can these two health check work together in haproxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, if the HTTP check fails a TCP connection then it will indicate the server is down. Therefore, you should not need both because theoretically the TCP check is built into the HTTP check.

Comment: This question is to understand whether this particular piece works in haproxy because I could not find enough information. I agree both the health checks are not required but the question is whether these two should work together in `haproxy`?